# Click on table cell value in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I have a table of values that include images, text and numbers.
I want to click on a particular text and haven't been able to do. I am new to e2e testing with protractor so please help.

I need to click on the text "Created By Test Automation"

```html
<td class="custom-t-act mat-cell cdk-column-name mat-column-name ng-tns-c15-3 ng-star-inserted"
    _ngcontent-c15="" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <h5 _ngcontent-c15="" class="mb-0 pointer" tabindex="0"
      ng-reflect-router-link="/projects/created-by-test-auto">
    <b _ngcontent-c15="" class="ng-tns-c15-3">Created by Test Automation</b>
  </h5>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly what the text would be there, then you are looking for [by.cssContainingText](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

```
element(by.cssContainingText('b', 'Created By Test Automation')).click();
```

otherwise, you could do something like this

```
$('[ng-reflect-router-link="/projects/created-by-test-auto"]').click();
```

to click exactly on `h5` directive with `ng-reflect-router-link` directive, which is set to `/projects/created-by-test-auto`.